Implications of loading whole HTML pages/components using XHR/Fetch calls
I have an application with raw Javascript on the front-end built into an ASP.NET MVC application. I have decided to make it into a Single-Page Application, with the content being loaded using ASP.NET's View Components.
In order to achieve this, whenever the user requests the content I am making a fetch call to a server side HomeController method, which renders and returns the relevant View Component's HTML. I am then simply passing that HTML into a div container on the page, like in the example below:
var viewComponent = await fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'
});

var viewComponentHtml = await viewComponent.text();
$('#containerId').html(viewComponentHtml);

The HTML that is being rendered and returned from API calls is independent of any user input.
When I want to unload the view component and load another one, I simply drop the HTML in the div, like in the example below:
$('#containerId').html("");

I have done this to simplify object lifetime and binding/unbinding events to controls. I have quite a few different forms in the application with some complex events attached to controls.
I am wondering simply if this is an ok thing to do? I am worried if there are any implications of this that I haven't considered as this seems to not be a standard practice. Does anyone know if this would cause any issues with performance/security?
I have considered the implications on security with a possible XSS vulnerability, but I really can't see how this would be worse than simply loading the scripts on page load. Using developer tools on any page out there shows me that there is a network call being made to retrieve the static files on page load, which seems to be the same as what I am doing here, except I am doing it on demand via a fetch call.

Well fetching entire HTML pages is pretty much the origin of the Web.

Nothing really 'bad' about this, per se, however there are better ways. For example, making REST API call to return lightweight JSON responses which you then use to build the UI on the front end. This is the general pattern most modern SPA frameworks use, ie. Angular, React, etc.

"which renders and returns the relevant View Component's HTML" - its not that bad, it just the response will be pretty heavy. this approach was used before by aspnet [tag:webform]'s UpdatePanel. they just dump an entire section's html in the response and chug it into a living DOM.

If your website is complex and contains many components, you can use ajax to load the components as lazy loading, it can improve UX performance.
But if your website is simple, you should not use it because it makes your website slow and not SEO

How about $('#containerId').load(url)
